# How much cost by using Container, Column, Row? ( in Flutter)

Tags: flutter, containers, row

How much cost by using Container and Column, or Row?
I use one of these three for a trivial things, I want to know how much it costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know the purpose of using above three widgets.

**Container**

- Takes exactly one child widget
- Rich alignment and styling options available
- Flexible width (e.g. child width, available width, …)
- Perfect for custom styling and alignment

**Row/Column**

- Takes multiple (unlimited) child widgets
- Alignment options available, but there are no
- Always takes full available height (column) /width (row)
- Must-use if widgets sit next
  to/above each other

**Conclussion** 
If you can solve same problem with **Container** or **Row/Column** then I would suggest you to use Container. It takes less time/cost to render comparing to Row/Column.